# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in table oracle

Tags: oracle, ddl

i have a table in apex oracle, i have a goal, constantly see the current date and time in the table after updating it. Someone can tell you how to do it.
For example:

```
Current date
10.10.2019 16:20:39
```

And after updating this table:

```
Current date
10.10.2019 16:21:39
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use triggers to achieve what you wanted. triggers are queries which fire on any CRUD actions.

So according to your scenario you need to create a trigger to update the current date and time column when updating your table row.

Hope this might help you 
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers.aspx

Comment: Well, yes, but - this is Oracle, not MySQL. Besides, column's DEFAULT value is a better choice as you let database take care about it, not custom-written trigger.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this syntax :

`ALTER TABLE tab MODIFY current_date DEFAULT SYSDATE`

provided your table already has `current_date` column of date type,

Use `ALTER TABLE tab ADD current_date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE` if it's a non-existing column yet.